# Selenium - To capture screen shots from two monitors

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I have a PC with two monitors and I would like to capture screen shots of two monitors. I am using the below code and it captures the screen shot from first monitor only but not the second one.

```
public void getScreenshotThroughRobot(String filename) throws IOException, AWTException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    String format = "jpg";
    filename = filename + "-FullScreenshot." + format;

    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
    ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(filename));
}
```

If my browser opened in first monitor, screen capture is fine but if it opened in second then it is taking screen shot from the first monitor only.

Either it has to capture screen shots from 2 monitors or the active one where browser is present.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if (driver instanceof TakesScreenshot) {
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
    File screenshotFile = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    //feel free to move or rename the file as you see fit.
}else{ /* unsupported*/ }
```

In my experience this takes the screenshot of the browser only, but this may differ by driver.

**EDIT TO ADD** `driver` is an instance of `WebDriver`.  It's a little unclear from your question if this is what you're doing.  If it isn't and you can clarify your selenium usage I'll try to help.

Comment: I have already tried this and it was even worser, I was getting a blank screen shot.

Comment: Hmm, suggest you fiddle with the above approach.  Seems to be the more vanilla option and makes sense to me.  How are you running the browser?  If it's headless, you may get that problem.